# Measuring distances between screen pixels on Linux

Tags: linux, screenshot

Does there exist software for Linux that will allow me to measure distances between two pixels? Possibly with a zoom feature.

Comment: Are the 2 pixels on the same line vertically or horizontally?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul They don't need to be, but usually, yeah.

Comment: Then you should state it in your question, and check whether the answer you accepted actually works in oblique.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I hope you understand that measuring "diagonal" distances also involves specifying a metric, such as the Manhattan metric, ... and that would be too involved for this kind of question, I think.

Comment: Without a metric, it could just say "The distance between the two pixels is 249 pixels vertically, 1263 pixels horizontally". If you keep the current answer as accepted, better add "vertically or horizontally" to your question. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's [**screenruler**](http://gnomecoder.wordpress.com/screenruler/) for Gnome/GTK desktop environments, and [**kruler**](https://projects.kde.org/projects/kde/kdegraphics/kruler) for KDE.

You can install either from most repositories:

```
sudo aptitude install screenruler
sudo aptitude install kruler
```

or

```
sudo yum install screenruler
sudo yum install kruler
```

I'm on KDE at the moment, so here's a screenshot for kruler:

[image: kruler]

Or if you want to take a rectangle selection measurement, there's [**xmeasure**](https://code.google.com/p/xmeasure/).

It runs from the terminal and needs compiling first. You can do that by running:

```
gcc -o xmeasure xmeasure.c -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11
```

In the same directory as where you've saved the `xmeasure.c` file, then run:

```
./xmeasure
```

Here's a screenshot of the output (and compilation):

[image: xmeasure]

Comment: `screenruler` can only measure horizontal or vertical, not oblique.

Comment: No zoom in `kruler`